# Image button in kivy is not concise

Tags: python, kivy

if I press around my image button it clicks, I only want when the image is clicked that it opens not the surroundings can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Override `on_touch_down` to call `super().on_touch_down` only if the touch meets your collision requirements.

Comment: im unfamiliar with the documentation,  can you help me find a way it could be implemented in this code `def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                                       super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
                                      self.profileimage = ImageButton(source=                          "icons/profilepic.png", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.65})
                                      self.profileimage.bind(on_release= self.imagechange)
                                      self.add_widget(self.profileimage)`